# GET REST pipe buffer into response

Tags: node.js, rest, file, pipe, buffer

I am trying to send a file via a GET endpoint.
My file is fetched from another resource which responds with the buffer.

How can I once I have the buffer, stream it to the response or what would I have to convert it to, in order to be able to pipe it?

What I tried so far was following:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const stream = require('stream');

const fileBuffer = await fetch(fileDownloadURL, {});
const fileSize = Buffer.byteLength(fileBuffer);
const bufferStream = new stream.PassThrough();
​
bufferStream.end(fileBuffer);
bufferStream
    .pipe(res)
    .on('error', error => next(error));
​
res.set({
    'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': '*, Content-disposition, Content-Length',
    'Content-Type': 'document',
    'Content-Length': fileSize,
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-disposition, Content-Length',
    'Content-disposition': `attachment;filename=${filename}`
});
```

My response was plain binary (I test the requests with insomnia). Since insomnia has the feature of showing content visually, I expected it to show the file. The file would be the type `.docx`.

Comment: Can you please edit the question and add which library you are using for the request?

Comment: Extension `docx` is with the "Mime type"(Content-Type) is `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document` though I'm not sure if it's related to the reason for your error